# Copy Pointer values

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

Just a doubt here. I have 2  pointer to pointers..  **m1   ,   **m2    and m2 is initialized as :-

```
m2 =( int **) calloc( 5, sizeof( int *));
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)   
m2[i] = (int *)calloc( 8, sizeof(int));
```

And the pointer has  values.. just like 2d arrays..  at every position.

can I just do like --

```
m1 = m2;
free(m2);  // then use m1 as m2 ??
```

Really Sorry if its a simple question.. and please whats the proper way to copy m2 to m1 and free m2. 
Thanks.

Comment: regarding the calls to 'calloc()'  1) in C, do not cast the returned value  2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful (!= NULL)

Comment: Thanks for informing :) & of course I know it..

Answer (score 0):

No, `m1 = m2` will just make `m1` point to the same memory as `m2`. It doesn't copy the array.

When you then go and free that memory that both `m1` and `m2` point to, both pointers will be invalidated.

Btw `free(m2)` only deallocates the array of `int*`. You need to deallocate the `int` arrays in `m2` as well:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)   
    free(m2[i]);
free(m2);
```

Comment: Thanks. So  I need to allocate for m1 separately and assign each elements indivisually??

Comment: Yes. Instead of manually assigning you can also use [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

Comment: I am greatful. I ll look into that.  Another small doubt.    If I pass the pointer's  address into a function and allocate memory to the pointer in that function.. then does it remains after the function vanishes from stack? And can i use the memory allocated in the calling function?

Comment: If the memory is allocated dynamically, yes.